# Count the best from column league

Tags: mysql

I have table builded in sql fiddle. The query counting how much is longest run in column `more` withe value VG1 before we come to VG2. Its using 'pero' to count it. This is working.

Now i have column MIX, and i need to edit this query to count the best longest run from column league='MIX'.

This is current state of query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM results JOIN (SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d.%m.%Y')) AS d FROM results WHERE more != 'VG1' AND home = 'pero') dt ON STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d.%m.%Y') > dt.d WHERE home = 'pero';
```

SQLfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21dd8/1/0

New version:
    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8de48/3/0

Comment: According to `SQLFiddle` and your description, it's not clear for your question, could you please post your desired result or more details about question?

Comment: Show what you want for Expected Results.

Comment: I will update fiddle. sec

Comment: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8de48/3/0) this is new version. So now we have 'kero' in home value with 5 count, and pero with 4. They are in same league of MAX. Now i need to count which is the longest run in MAX league of this fields.

Comment: Great, so you have a new fiddle. If we can decipher what you wrote above, and with that left pane window from the new fiddle, what is a table representation of your Expected Results?